# Excel - copying to different instance removes decimal places

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I have a number which is the output of a calculation in one of the cells in Excel Spreadsheet A.  When I copy this cell and paste as value in Spreadsheet B, which is open in a different instance of Excel, some of the decimal places mysteriously disappear.  I was surprised by this, so I copied and pasted the value in Spreadsheet A as a value, then copied and pasted this value from A to B, and it still changed.

in Spreadsheet A, the value is:

2258.07102745522

When copied and pasted to Spreadsheet B (in another instance), the value is:

2258.071027

Never encountered this before, and I work extensively with Excel.  What is causing this?

Comment: When you increase/decrease the number of decimal points for the cell in question within the second instance what happens?  You are copying the value of the cell, so none of the formatting information, is being copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy between different *instances* of Excel (and not just different *worksheets* or *files*), they don’t consider each other being the same program, and interact simplified through Windows’ clipboard.
For such transfers, the complete Excel cell information (format, number, formula, color, etc.) gets replaced by a dumb text, and then pasted as such. This text reflects what you *see* in a cell, not what the underlying Excel knows what is in the cell; therefore number of digits shown is relevant, same as potential formats with text pieces (for example, a number 24 that is formatted to show “24 h” becomes the text “24 h” when pasted).

You can avoid this by working in the same instance (which has some other consequences, like Excel-wide settings getting overwritten for all files by the last file opened...)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - SOLVED

I discovered that if, in Session A, I format the cell so that all of the decimal places are showing, and then copy this number from A to B, all of the decimal places now appear in B.

This does intuitively make sense, since what you are pasting into Session B is just a dumb number, and it presumably copies only visible decimal places on this basis.

This seems to be a very rare example of a situation where formatting matters for anything other than aesthetic reasons in Excel.

Comment: Standard precision in LibreOffice Calc (and Excel?) is 16 digits. Type in a number `1.23456789012345678901234567890` and you get `1.23456789012346` just after you have hit `ENTER`. Move the decimal point to any place you wish. If you get less, then it is a copy and paste error, or a formatting issue (formatting for DISPLAY, CTRL-1 you know).